# Change URl tabs without page refresh NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using material ui tabs, and I'm pushing the tabs to URL. I want to push the tab but not refresh the page every-time I change the tab. Here is my code, and I'm using shallow:true but the problem remains:

```
const tabs = [
  { label: 'Details', value: 'details' },
  { label: 'Purchases', value: 'purchases' },
  { label: 'Money Transfer', value: 'moneyTransfer' },
  {label:'User Activity',value:'userActivity'},
  {label:'User Logs',value:'userLogs'}
];
const {
    query: { UsersId,tab },
  } = router
const handleTabsChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string): void => {

  router.push({
    pathname: `/dashboard/twigUsers/${UsersId}`,query: { tab:value}},undefined,{ shallow: true });
};

             <Tabs
              indicatorColor="primary"
              onChange={handleTabsChange}
              scrollButtons="auto"
              sx={{ mt: 3 }}
              textColor="primary"
              value={tab}
              variant="scrollable"
            >
              {tabs.map((tab) => (
                <Tab
                  key={tab.value}
                  label={tab.label}
                  value={tab.value}
                />
              ))}
            </Tabs>

{tab === 'details' && (
             <UsersDetailsContainer user={user} userId={UsersId}/>
            )}
            {tab === 'purchases' && <PurchasesListTable userDetailsId={userDetailsId}/>}
            {tab === 'moneyTransfer' && <MoneyTransferListTable userDetailsIdMT={userDetailsIdMT} />}
            {tab==='userActivity' &&<UserActivity/>}
            {tab==='userLogs' &&<UserLogs user={user} userId={twigUsersId}/>}
```

Comment: What do you mean by page refresh? If you're referring to the fact that the component will re-render then that's expected when navigation occurs. State will still be kept, though.

Comment: The whole page is refreshing also the data that are not in the component, the state of the whole data in the page its gone

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As it is now it's not possible to reproduce what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent propagation, else this will actually just propagate to the parent, and will refresh the site.

```
const handleTabsChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string): void => {
  event.preventDefault();

  router.push(
    {
      pathname: `/dashboard/twigUsers/${UsersId}`,
      query: { tab: value },
    },
    undefined,
    { shallow: true }
  );
};
```

check out an implementation in action [here](https://github.com/CodeForAfrica/TwoopsTrackerUI/blob/main/src/components/Tabs/index.js)

Comment: Still refreshing, its this a nextjs thing refreshing pages all the time?

Comment: that is strange, because i have a similar setup here, I will edit to add it in the code so you see.

Comment: Thank you but for me it dosent work

Comment: can you provide a full example then? It seems something else is triggering the refresh @Emily

Comment: I have changed the whole logic im storing tabs in redux so now the page its not refreshing

Comment: how I can get 'tab' value from 'query' object in server component?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the whole logic in order to work, I have stored the tabs in redux saga here is the code:
**Redux part**

```
// utils
import axios from 'axios';
import produce from 'immer';
import creator from '../../../utils/actionCreator';
import { put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';

// consts
export const REQUEST = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/REQUEST';
export const SUCCESS = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/SUCCESS';
export const FAILURE = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/FAILURE';

export const UPDATE_REQUEST = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/UPDATE_REQUEST';
export const UPDATE_SUCCESS = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/UPDATE_SUCCESS';
export const UPDATE_FAILURE = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/UPDATE_FAILURE';
export const CLEAR = '@app/tabs/get/getUsersDetailsTabs/CLEAR';

// initial state
const initalState = {
  error: '',
  loading: false,
  success: false,
  tabs:[]
};

// reducer
const reducer = (state = initalState, { payload, ...action }: AnyAction) =>
  produce(state, (draft) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case REQUEST:
        draft.tabs = payload;
        break;
      case SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.tabs = payload;
        break;
      case FAILURE:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = payload;
        break;
      case UPDATE_REQUEST:
        draft.loading = true;
        break;
      case UPDATE_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.success = true;
        break;
      case UPDATE_FAILURE:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = payload;
        break;
      case CLEAR:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = '';
        draft.tabs = [];
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });

// actions
const actions = {
  request: (tabs) => creator(REQUEST, tabs),
  success: (tabs) => creator(SUCCESS, tabs),
  failure: (tabs) => creator(FAILURE, tabs),

  updateRequest: (tabs) => creator(UPDATE_REQUEST, tabs),
  updateSuccess: (tabs) => creator(UPDATE_SUCCESS, tabs),
  updateFailure: (tabs) => creator(UPDATE_FAILURE, tabs),

  clear: () => creator(CLEAR)
};

// sagas
const sagas = {
    *getTabs(tabs){
    return{
        type:REQUEST,
        payload:tabs
    }
    }
};

// watcher
const watcher = function* watch() {
  yield takeLatest(REQUEST, sagas.getTabs);
};

// exports
export { actions, watcher };
export default reducer;
```

**Dispatch the tabs**

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('details');
const handleTabsChange = (event: ChangeEvent<{}>,newValue): void => {
   console.log(newValue,"new value")
  setValue(newValue);
};
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTabs.request(
      [ { label: 'Details', value: 'details' },
      { label: 'Purchases', value: 'purchases' },
      { label: 'Money Transfer', value: 'moneyTransfer' },
      {label:'User Activity',value:'userActivity'},
      {label:'User Logs',value:'userLogs'}]
    ));
  },[]);
  const { tabs:tabs } = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.tabs);
```

**Tabs**

```
  <Tabs
              indicatorColor="primary"
              onChange={handleTabsChange}
              scrollButtons="auto"
              sx={{ mt: 3 }}
              textColor="primary"
              value={value}
              variant="scrollable"
            >
              {tabs.map((tab) => (
                <Tab
                  key={tab.value}
                  label={tab.label}
                  value={tab.value}
                />
              ))}
            </Tabs>

{value === 'details' && (
             <UsersDetailsContainer user={user} userId={twigUsersId}/>
            )}
            {value === 'purchases' && <PurchasesListTable userDetailsId={userDetailsId}/>}
            {value === 'moneyTransfer' && <MoneyTransferListTable userDetailsIdMT={userDetailsIdMT} />}
            {value==='userActivity' &&<UserActivity/>}
            {value==='userLogs' &&<UserLogs user={user} userId={twigUsersId}/>}
```